# Open subscheme of affine dedekind scheme is affine ( Liu's Exercise 4.1.9.)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to solve the Liu's Algebraic Geometry and arithmetic curves, Exercise 4.1.9.

> Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine Dedekind scheme. We are going to show that every open subscheme $U$ of $X$ is affine. We may assume that $U$ is the complement of a closed point $x_0$. ( Since nonemepty open subsets of $X$ are the subsets of the form $X -\{x_1, . . . , x_k\}$ for finitely many closed points $x_1, . . . , x_k ∈ X$ ( c.f. [https://math.berkeley.edu/~tb65536/AG_Final_Project.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Etb65536/AG_Final_Project.pdf) ), by induction, it is enough to show that for every closed point $x_0 \in X$, the complement $U :=X - \{ x_0 \}$ is affine. )

(a) Let $\mathfrak{m}_0$ be the maximal ideal of $A$ corresponding to $x_0$. Let $t\in A$ be such that $t\mathcal{O}_{X,x_0} = \mathfrak{m}_0 \mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}$ and let $V(t)=\{x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. Show that for every $1\le i \le n$, there exists $t_i \in A$ such that $t_i \notin \mathfrak{m}_0$ and that $t_i$ generates the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$.

(b) Show that there exists an $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)-A$  (take $f = t^{-1} \prod_{1\le i\le n}t_i^{d_i}$ with large $d_i$).

(c), (d) Omitted.

I can't prove (b) ; i.e., I don't know how to choose such large $d_i$. C.f. for such $f$, I could prove that $f \notin A$, by using $A = \cap_{x\in X}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ so that $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}$. But how can we choose $d_i$ such that $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X}(U) = \cap_{u\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,u}$ ?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $t_i$ is in $A$ (so is $t$), and $V(t)=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$, so such an $f$ is in $\mathcal{O}_{X,u}$ for all $u \notin \{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$.

We need to show that, for all $i \neq 0$, $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$.

Take $d_i > v_{\mathfrak{m}_i}(t)$: then we can write $t_i^{d_i}=z_i t$ for some $z_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$ (this ring is Dedekind and local, hence a DVR). Then $f=z_i\prod_{j \neq i}{t_j^{d_j}} \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much !

Comment: When I woke up, there were some things I didn't understand. Where the condition $i \neq 0$ is used for showing that $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$? Argument of my own following your answer is as follows : If $ (\frac{t}{1})$ is 'nonzero' ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_i} = A_{\mathfrak{m}_{x_i}}$, then $(\frac{t}{1}) = ( (\frac{t_i}{1})^{n_i})$ for some $n_i \ge 0$ since $\frac{t_i}{1}$ is an uniformizing element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$. In fact, we can take $n_i = v_{\mathfrak{m}_i}(t)$ (?).

Comment: So $(\frac{t_i}{1})^{n_i} = z_i \frac{t}{1} $ for some $z_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$ so that $\frac{t_i^{n_i}}{t}=z_i$. But can we guarantee that $(\frac{t}{1})$ is nonzero ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$? I guessed that this is true by $i\neq 0 $ but looking back, I'm not sure. Am I following your answer well?

Comment: Uhm. O.K. I think that $(\frac{t}{1})$ is nonzero ideal. The form $f = z_i \prod_{j\neq i }t_j^{d_j}$ is contained in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_i}$ for only $i\neq 0$ !.